# Node.js cannot find module - interfering with cygwin on Windows

Tags: node.js, cygwin, twitter-bootstrap, less, npm

I'm testing the Bootstrap framework (from Twitter) and try to build it locally after installing Node.js. It fails because it cannot find the less module (which I have also installed with 'npm install -g less'):

```
C:\Users\geir\code\bootstrap>make
lessc html/less/bootstrap.less > html/css/bootstrap.css

node.js:201
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\cygdrive\c\Users\geir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\less\bin\lessc'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:332:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
    at Array.0 (module.js:479:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
Makefile:2: recipe for target `all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

The reason why it fails is because "cygdrive\" is prepended to the folder hierarchy when make is looking for the module, I've verified thtat 'lessc' is actually found in C:\Users\geir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\less\bin\lessc, and I can run it from the commandline.

I've tried the following without any success:

- Reorder folders in the PATH env variable, so that node.js and npm comes before cygwin - same outcome.
- Remove cygwin from PATH - make command is stops working.
- install 'less' with/without '-g' parameter (npm)
- Reinstall node.js

Anyone clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call make from the Cygwin Terminal. Open the Cygwin Terminal, then cd into cygwin's alias for your C:\Users\geir\code\bootstrap folder, then run make:

```
geir@WINHOSTNAME ~
$cd /cygdrive/c/Users/geir/code/bootstrap
geir@WINHOSTNAME /cygdrive/c/Users/geir/code/bootstrap
$make
```