# How to run Mocha tests on windows node.js ( Error: Cannot find module 'C:\cygdrive\c\Users )

Tags: node.js, makefile, cygwin, mocha.js

I'm trying to run an app in windows and this app has some mocha tests. I need make. I read this

[Mocha requires make. Can't find a make.exe that works on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779700/mocha-requires-make-cant-find-a-make-exe-that-works-on-windows)

and this

[Node.js cannot find module - interfering with cygwin on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093679/node-js-cannot-find-module-interfering-with-cygwin-on-windows)

I have the app in the Github directory (outside of cygwin directory structure ) and i installed the windows version of node.

I Tried using powershell and setting the alias as suggested but i always get

> ```
> > module.js:340
> >     throw err;
> >           ^ Error: Cannot find module 'C:\cygdrive\c\Users\Nicola\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\bin\mocha'
> >     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
> >     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
> >     at Module.runMain (module.js:487:10)
> >     at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9) Makefile:5: recipe for target `test' failed make: ***
> > [test] Error 1
> ```

and i have mocha installed in that directory ( BTW why doesn't he look for mocha in the node_modules subdir? ). The problems seems to be the `C:\cygdrive\c\Users` part how do i take that off?

I also tried copying the file to my home/ directory under cygwin but i got

```
./node_modules/.bin/mocha: line 1: ../mocha/bin/mocha: No such file or directory
Makefile:5: recipe for target `test' failed
make: *** [test] Error 127
```

what should i do?

Answer (score 22):

Best way I've been able to do it is to first install mocha in the directory as a dev dependency (i.e: `npm install mocha --save-dev`). Then in the `npm test` command inside `package.json`, use `"test": "mocha"`. This way, you can easily run `npm test` in CLI for standardization. You can now either setup your tests in a `test/` directory or have a simple `test.js` file in case you only have a few tests to run. Also, don't forget to have a `mocha.opts` file with your [options](http://mochajs.org/#usage). This should work, especially if you're using Git Bash (I tried on windows CMD and it works too!).

Comment: I found adding project-dir\node_module\.bin to the path makes things work as expected with the package_json entry for test as: "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha test -u bdd -R spec" }

Comment: @Amitabh I wouldn't recommend adding node modules as a PATH variable. YMMV but you will be tied down to one version of mocha for projects.

Comment: after running `npm install mocha --save-dev`, a simple call to `npm init` created the `package.json` file for me. I created a simple Mocha test file `test.js` (see the [Getting Started section](https://mochajs.org/)) and ran it at the command line with `npm test`. Fantastic answer!!

Answer (score 3):

You can configure the npm test command inside the package.json file to run mocha using the syntax below.

```
  "scripts": {
      "test": "node node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --recursive"
  },
```

Answer (score 3):

My solution was run the command `node ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha`

It happened because mocha is not variable of environment of the Windows.

Comment: What is not said already in other answers?

Answer (score 0):

when you write "make test" and you receive this:

```
./node_modules/.bin/mocha: line 1: ../mocha/bin/mocha: No such file or directory
Makefile:5: recipe for target `test' failed
make: *** [test] Error 127
```

it means that you don't have Mocha installed in your project. Put mocha in your package.json and run 'npm install':

```
{
"name": "appName"
, "version": "0.0.1"
, "private": true
, "dependencies": {

  "mocha": "1.3.0"
, "should": "1.0.0"

}
}
```

after that i got my tests running on windows.